# How to disable mod_mono by default?

Tags: apache, cpanel, mod-mono

Mod mono is enabled by default for all accounts on cPanel server.

I installed it using EasyApache. How can I disable it by default for all accounts and how do I enable it just for a specific account?
cpanel 11 - modmono 2 - apache 2.2

Answer (score 1):

The global option

- MonoAutoApplication disable

Need to be addedd in the global/default vhost config. In fact you can see this post here:

[Httpd.conf multiple VirtualHost sections (was: Mono ASP.NET MVC AutoHosting issues)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1286776/httpd-conf-multiple-virtualhost-sections-was-mono-asp-net-mvc-autohosting-issu)

Then you can enable it for a specific Vhost:

- AddHandler mono .aspx .ascx .asax .ashx .config .cs .asmx .axd
  This can be done manually, or trough each account Cpanel interface!

---

Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

if I recall correctly, you need to disable it globaly
  MonoAutoApplication disable

and enable it for desired Vhosts
 AddHandler mono .aspx .ascx .asax .ashx .config .cs .asmx .axd

There is much more detail in cpanel doc
docs.cpanel.net/twiki/pub/AllDocumentation/TrainingResources/TrainingSlides08/Modmono.pdf

Let me know :)

Comment: can you kindly submit more details .. where exactly to add " MonoAutoApplication disable " ??