# Precompiling ASP.NET MVC on Mono with Web Deployment Project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, deployment, mono, precompile

I am trying to precompile and deploy my ASP.NET MVC application from Visual Studio 2008 to a server running Mono 2.4 using a Visual Studio 2008 Web Deployment Project.  Whenever I go to the website, however, I get an error message:

> This is a marker file generated by the
>   precompilation tool, and should not be
>   deleted!

Has anyone got this working?  Is there a better way to precompile and deploy an MVC application from Visual Studio 2008 to Mono?

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure that when you used the aspnet_compiler command, you specified the virtual directory where the applications would reside with the -v command.  For instance, if you want to build and serve a stock ASP.NET MVC application, Mvc1, from localhost/Mvc1, you would need to make sure you use the -v /Mvc1 switch:

aspnet_compiler -f -p c:\projects\Mvc1 -v /Mvc1 c:\test\output

Since this is an ASP.NET MVC application, I would also suggest making sure you explicitly configured Apache mod_mono, rather than depending on AutoHosting.  I discussed why in [my answer to "Mono 2.4, AutoHosting and MVC"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/699487/mono-2-4-autohosting-and-mvc/703196#703196).

You can now use the [Apache mod_mono configuration tool](http://www.go-mono.com/config-mod-mono/) hosted on the mono website.